# ADF expression builder extract portion of string before certain character

Tags: azure-data-factory

This is what the expression looks like

[Expression builder /output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojkPh.png)

I need to get the substring teBatches_raw to only return everything before the _ character.

Expected output

teBatches

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Azure Data Factory (ADF) and Synapse Pipelines have an [expression language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions) with a number of functions that can do this type of thing.  You can use `split` for example to split your string by underscore (_) into an array and then grab the first item from the array, eg something like:

```
@{split(pipeline().Pipeline, '_')[0]}
```

Or with a variable, not using string interpolation:

```
@split(variables('varInput'), '_')[0]
```

My results for the variable line:

[image: results]

Comment: Any update on this?